# What is Best Practice for migrating SQL 2012 system databases to failover cluster?

Tags: sql-server, failovercluster, sql-server-2012

What is the best practice for copying **system databases** when migrating from SQL Server 2012 (no SP) to 2012 SP2 in a Failover Cluster?
Just backup and restore? Or, script out and script in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrating to a new SQL Server machine: should master database be restored?](http://serverfault.com/questions/386715/migrating-to-a-new-sql-server-machine-should-master-database-be-restored)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to not migrate the system DBs.

Comment: A source for this best practice and some details as to why it's not might not be amiss here.

Comment: Not really anything online. See duplicate. Source: Years of working with SQL Server?